# How to make a very thin plate with some resistance

Tags: resistors, dc, resistivity

I'm doing experiments with electric fields and would (ideally) like a very thin solid box (not hollow) as shown in this picture:

[image]

It would need a very thin \$h\$ (of about 200 um at most, if possible), an \$l\$ of about 10 cm and a \$w\$ that would allow a resistance of about 180 ohms. Since $$ R = \rho \frac{w}{h*l} $$

that would mean w would depend on the resistivity \$ \rho \$ of the material.

Also, it would really help if the top and bottom surfaces are covered with an even thinner insulator (~5 um would be possible? The smaller the better).

I was thinking about a silicon wafer. Some shops sell it with an \$ h = 130um \$, \$ \rho = 0.01 \Omega m \$ , \$ l = 10 cm\$ which would mean \$ w = 23cm\$. But if \$ \rho \$ is even smaller than better (as long as \$ l > 1cm \$ its good so I can still work on it with my hands)

But I never bought a wafer before and dicing it (a "circular" wafer doesn't suit me at all) seems to be nontrivial, specially for more or less precise (< 30% error) cuts and unfortunately I'm not so handy (I think I will break most of them)...

Also, I saw that we can purchase the wafer with a coating but as far as can tell (which maybe is wrong), its not just for the top and bottom sides, the coating would reach every side of the wafer. Since I want to plug in a power supply to the front and back sides of the wafer, these sides need to be "accessible". Even without coating, I don't know if it possible to solder some wire directly into the silicon to connect it to the power supply...?

Another solution could be graphite or germanium plates?

Is there a better idea than the wafer? If the wafer is a "good" solution, can you recommend some (European would help) manufacturer?

If no thin (small h) solution is possible, then it could be relaxed to \$ h = 1 mm \$ if needed, but having a top/down insulator would be extremely helpful.

Also, please keep in mind that is a hobby experiment, not an application and certainly not for a commercial system so I can spend some money, but not $1000 :).

Comment: the "box" is a void, or a solid

Comment: what's inside the box? ... is there a lid?

Comment: You can get [p-type or n-type wafers](https://waferpro.com/what-are-p-type-and-n-type-silicon-wafers/) that will have a different \$\rho\$ than intrinsic silicon. Might consider that option.

Comment: Thick film technology would be a possibility. The substrates are thin. The resistive paste is available in many different conductivities. You could put a thin edge of conductive paste to allow the edges to be soldered. Unfortunately, you will have difficulty applying the paste evenly without the proper equipment.

Comment: What do the dimensions matter to the electric field?  The field within the box is independent of the dimensions, scaled appropriately. You can probe the field within a scaled-up box much more easily.  If the purpose is field outside the box, that can be implemented with any finite resistance, and roughness of the box probably doesn't matter as much or at all, i.e. consider a cylindrical or wirewound figure instead.

Comment: Sounds somewhat like a CD or DVD...very thin aluminum disk sandwiched in clear plastic. The trick will be to gain access to the aluminum. I don't know its thickness, and hence resistivity is unknown.

Comment: The copper on a standard PCB is 35 μm thick, so if you make L very long or W very narrow you can get 10 Ω out of that. It's about 0.5 mΩ/⧠, so your L/W ratio needs to be about 20,000. For a 6-mil wide trace (easy for most PCB fabs), that's 120 inches, which you could achieve on a reasonably sized board by simply zigzagging back and forth a bunch of times.

Comment: @Jason + jsotola I edited the question (its a solid box acting as a resistor)

Comment: @periblepsis yes, I think so. The Si with rho = 0.01 that I saw as a doped wafer (resistivity would be much higher if it was just pure Si)

Comment: @Mattman944 Thank you for the suggestion, but how could I go around to purchase that thick film? Did a quick google search and did not come up with many answers.

Comment: @Tim Williams I agree with you and there is a 99.99999....999% chance I won't discover anything new. Its just an experiment.

Comment: @ glen_geek maybe I misunderstood, but as far as I could tell, CD/DVD have aluminum which, although might be very thin, is still a very good conductor so reaching 180 ohms could be hard

Comment: @Hearth maybe you have a good idea. But if the "height" of the copper is ~35um and width of the trace is ~5um (and I guess I could have a trace distance of another ~5 um)  I think I would need -3m trace to get to 180 ohms. So maybe if it is possible to reduce the trace width to 1um...could get L=63cm...not bad. Just a note: I don't want to zigzag...it needs to be straight

Comment: Search for *thick film resistive paste*. Several substrates are used, Alumina is common. But, it is doubtful that you will be able to lay down a consistent layer of paste without special equipment. Your best bet would be to collaborate with a University, if you can find one that still has a working thick-film lab, and your project has enough scientific interest to get a professor to help you. My thick-film lab course was in 1980.

Comment: Graphite might work, but it would be thicker than you want. There was a video online of someone demonstrating the *hall effect* using a simple setup. I decided that it was bogus, but my interest was piqued and I attempted to create my own demonstration. I needed a rectangular piece of resistive material similar to what you want. I bought a doped silicon wafer, but it is nearly impossible to make electrical contact with it. Thick pencil lead, like a carpenter would use, was the most promising, but my demonstration was mostly a failure. https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B002FX2RPG

Comment: @mabeco It can't be 5 μm wide--most PCB fabs won't go thinner than about 3 or 4 mils, and that gets expensive.

Comment: @Hearth I believe you are right, it's very difficult to be smaller than 3 mils. Do you know if instead of copper it could be another material with higher resistivity?

Comment: @mabeco Not anything a standard PCB fab is equipped to work with. A wafer fab could probably do a 1 μm thick (or even thinner) layer of ti-tungsten, though.

Comment: @Mattman944 was searching like you said (think film resistive paste). For the paste itself didn't find much information, more about resistors like this: https://www.elprocus.com/thick-film-resistor/. But it seems that the resistive material is quite "small" compared to the whole resistor. The metals on the edges create additional electrical field than what I was trying to study.

Answer (score 2):

Thick Film Method. Not a perfect answer, but I can't put a picture in my comments.

The conductive area allows you to connect to the resistive plane. You can solder to the conductive area. Otherwise, there is no easy way to connect to the resistive plane.

I have assumed that you want to connect to the ends. If you want more of a point connection, use a small area of conductive paste.

layers are applied with a screen process, similar to silk screen, except the screen is metal.

The conductive layer is put down first. After each layer, you need to cure at a high temperature. You need a slight overlap between the conductive layer and resistive layer, the registration between layers is never perfect.

[image]